How do I write a predicate to compare multiple many to many items to each other?
I am trying to return a list of items that may match multiple tags
For example given below:
item1 with tag1 and tag2
item2 with tag1 only.
If I have tag1 and tag2 selected I would like to return only item one. However currently I am returning anything that matches any tags.
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { item in                  
    item.tags?.allSatisfy{ tag in                      
    tag.active == true } ?? false              
}              
_items = Query(filter: predicate)

Model:
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
class Item {
var title: String
@Relationship(inverse: \\Tag.items)
var tags: \[Tag\]?

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
        
    }

}

import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
class Tag {
var active: Bool = false
var name: String
var items: \[Item\]?

    init(name: String, active: Bool) {
        self.active = active
        self.name = name
        
    }

}

So far my code will return an item that contains an active tag however I would like it to return only items that match ALL active tags
For example below, Item 1 should not show because it only matches one of the active tags, not both.


It’s not clear to me what you want, are you saying that an Item needs to be related to all active tags to be included rather than that the tags related to an item needs to be all active? What I read is the first alternative but the second one makes more sense to me.

@JoakimDanielson thats right. If I have tag1 and tag1 active in my app, I want to return only items that contain both those tags. Items should match all tags not just any tags, if that makes sense.

So you need to know all active tags and then match items against that collection?

@JoakimDanielson yes I believe so.  So I can return items that have all the active tags not just any of them, which is what it does now.
